# Authorization Error from beginCopyFromURL API from Javascript library (@azure/storage-blob) when executed from minikube

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-node-sdk

I have application registered in Azure and it has Storage Account Contributor role. I am trying to copy content from one account to another in same subscription by using SAS token. Below is code snippet for testing purpose. ***This code works perfectly fine from standalone node js but it fails when deployed in minikube pod with Authorization Error code 403***. Any suggestions/thoughts will be appreciated.

1. I have verified start and end date for signature.
2. Permissions are broader but they seem to correct.
3. For testing keeping expiry for 24 hrs.
4. If I copy sas url generated from failed code,I can download file from my host machine using azcopy command line. Looks like code fails only when executed from minikube pod.

```
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { BlobServiceClient, UserDelegationKey, ContainerSASPermissions, generateBlobSASQueryParameters } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

module.exports = function () {
  /*

  This function will receive an input that conforms to the schema specified in
  activity.json. The output is a callback function that follows node's error first
  convention. The first parameter is either null or an Error object. The second parameter
  of the output callback should be a JSON object that conforms to the schema specified
  in activity.json

 */
  this.execute = async function (input, output) {

    try {
      if (input.connection) {

        const containerName = input.sourcecontainer.trim()
        const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(input.connection.tenantId, input.connection.clientid, input.connection.clientsecret);
        const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
        // Enter your storage account name
        const account = input.sourceaccount.trim();
        const accounturl = 'https://'.concat(account).concat('.blob.core.windows.net')
        const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
          accounturl,
          credential);

        const keyStart = new Date()
        const keyExpiry = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400 * 1000)
        const userDelegationKey = await blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(keyStart, keyExpiry);

        console.log(userDelegationKey)

        const containerSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
          containerName,
          permissions: ContainerSASPermissions.parse("racwdl"),
          startsOn: new Date(),
          expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400 * 1000),
        },
          userDelegationKey, account).toString();

        const target = '/' + containerName + '/' + input.sourcefolder.trim() + '/' + input.sourcefilename.trim()
        const sastoken = accounturl + target + '?' + containerSAS
        console.log(sastoken)
        let outputData = {
          "sourcesas": sastoken
        }


      //Testing second action execution from same action for testing purpose.

      const containerName2 = 'targettestcontainer'
      const credential2 = new ClientSecretCredential(input.connection.tenantId, input.connection.clientid, input.connection.clientsecret);

      // Enter your storage account name
          
      const blobServiceClient2 = new BlobServiceClient(
         accounturl,
         credential2);

      const destContainer = blobServiceClient2.getContainerClient(containerName2);
      const destBlob = destContainer.getBlobClient('testfolder01' + '/' + 'test-code.pdf');
     
      const copyPoller = await destBlob.beginCopyFromURL(outputData.sourcesas);
      const result = await copyPoller.pollUntilDone();

        return output(null, outputData) 

      } 

    } catch (e) {

      console.log(e)
      return output(e, null)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [EmmaZhu-MSFT](https://github.com/EmmaZhu) for providing the solution. Simmilar issue also raise in [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/21977) Posting this as an answer to help other community member.

> From service side log, seems there's time skew between Azure Storage
> Service and the client, the start time used in source SAS token was
> later than server time.
>
> We'd suggest not using start time in SAS token to avoid this kind of
> failure caused by time skew.

**Reference : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/21977**